# pyenv does not use correct python version

Tags: python, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

using pyenv 2.0.3

when i'm in a folder with a python-version file, the python keeps using the system version which is 2.7.6. (not sure why it is 2.7.6 since i install 3.9.7 via brew).

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.16
```

looking via pyenv gives

```
$ pyenv which python
/Users/jaco/.pyenv/versions/trading/bin/python
```

Activating it already says it is activated.

i have

```
# pyenv
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

in my zshrc

also don't seem to have the bin folder of pyenv? is this new on the v2?

```
$ l /Users/jaco/.pyenv/bin
ls: /Users/jaco/.pyenv/bin: No such file or directory
```

Also setting `pyenv global 3.9.1` does not work, it keeps 2.7

Comment: It might be simpler to just use `~/.pyenv/versions/something/bin/python -m venv some_path` to create a virtualenv in `some_path` that uses a Pyenv-installed Python.

Answer (score 18):

The answer is to put the shims on the path

```
# pyenv
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PATH"
if which pyenv-virtualenv-init > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"; fi
#if which pyenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv init -)"; fi
```

Comment: Did you happen to run into this by installing pyenv natively initially but then upgrading via brew?

Comment: @MarcelWilson no, I always installed pyenv via brew. I did a brew upgrade I think which screwed it up.

Comment: This also worked for me with the fish shell

Comment: I get ```Failed to activate virtualenv.

Perhaps pyenv-virtualenv has not been loaded into your shell properly.``` with these changes. :/

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you're running MacOS and have installed `pyenv` via Homebrew, you'll need to do the following:

```sh
# Adjust the session-wide environment for your account.
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"' >> ~/.zprofile

# Enable autocompletion and all subcommands
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

From [pyenv installation docs](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation):

> MacOS note: If you installed Pyenv with Homebrew, you don't need to add the PYENV_ROOT= and PATH= lines. You also don't need to add commands into ~/.profile if your shell doesn't use it.

Answer (score 2):

I typed `pyenv versions` and it showed:

```
  system
  2.7.18
* 3.10.0 (set by PYENV_VERSION environment variable)
  3.8.13
```

Then I simply ran `unset PYENV_VERSION` and when I ran `pyenv versions` again it correclty selected the local version I intended (2.7.18).

Comment: is that the question? I understand he is asking for the python version

Answer (score 1):

I was on my `~` folder and trying to run `pyenv global 3.10.4` **BUT** `python -V` was only running `3.8.3` tried everything and was in despair.

The problem was that on my `~` there was a `.python-version` file pointing to `3.8.3`.

Solution: check and remove `.python-version`