# pyenv is using system python instead of virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, pyenv

I've been using pyenv for a long time, without any troubles. I set up it properly and everything worked.

However, while I was trying to solve another problem, I run some line which ruined my pyenv instalation.

Now, when I activate any virtualenv, it tries to use system's python instead of pyenv's:

```
$ pyenv activate foo
(foo) $ which python 
/usr/bin/python
(foo) $ pip --version
pip 20.3.4 from /home/rodrigo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

I'm not sure exactly which line was the one that ruined it, it may be the following: `(foo) $ pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` **from** the `foo` environment (I run it when it still worked), but may be another.

I already checked `~/.bashrc` file and it is ok; restarted the console and even changed to a different environment `foo2` and the problem is still there...

I already checked similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68345938/pyenv-does-not-use-correct-python-version) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471563/sytem-python-version-active-instead-of-local-pyenv-version), but those are related to miss-configurations which I already tested and are ok.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and pyenv  2.0.3-8-gad880754

**UPDATE** I re-installed pyenv but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 7):

I got it to work by changing `~/.zshrc`:

Change

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

to

```
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

and start a new shell.

Seems like this was a change that was introduced in 2.0.

Comment: awesome. This fixed the problem for me

Comment: I keep getting ```Failed to activate virtualenv.

Perhaps pyenv-virtualenv has not been loaded into your shell properly.
Please restart current shell and try again.
``` with this change.

Comment: This error suggests that pyenv-virtualenv might not have been correctly loaded into your shell.

Comment: To resolve this, follow these steps

Comment: ```git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv.git $(pyenv root)/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv```

Comment: ```eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)”```

Comment: ```source ~/.zshrc # or use ~/.bashrc or appropriate file for your shell```

Comment: This solution works for me too, but as a side effect my prompt stopped showing name of the virtual env (which I previously set by `pyenv local [virtual env. name]` in that folder).

Comment: By executing the command `export PS1="(basename $VIRTUAL_ENV)$PS1"`, you can add the name of the currently activated virtual environment to your shell prompt.